# Como saber si el correo ya ha sido registrado en firebase autenticacion, javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Me encuentro realizando una actualizacion de correo electronico para el usuario, pero antes necesito saber si el correo ya ha sido registrado anteriomente en firebase autentificacion.

De esta forma actualizo el correo electronico:

```
 if(administrador.correo != vm.editedItem.correo){
       console.log("ESTA ACTUALIZANDO CORREO");
       console.log(vm.editedItem);
       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(vm.editedItem.correo, vm.editedItem.contrasenia)
                                    .then(function(userCredential) {
                                        console.log("USER CREDENTIAL");
                                        console.log(userCredential);
                                        userCredential.user.updateEmail(vm.editedItem.correo)
                                        .then(function() {
                                            console.log("Correo actualizado");
                                        // Update successful.
                                        }).catch(function(error) {
                                            console.log("ERROR");
                                            console.log(error);
                                        // An error happened.
                                        });
                                    })
                              }
```

Pero antes de poder actualizar el correo electrónico debo validar si ya existe, si el correo existe, pues no es permitido actualizar correo y si el correo no existe por lo tanto que actualice el correo.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, **no deberías** hacer una actualización de correo, dentro del *callBack* de éxito del login. Ademas de que te estas logeando con el mismo correo que haces update `vm.editedItem.correo`.

Dicho esto, si deseas hacer update de un correo y que no coincida con uno ya existente, debes usar:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser; // Tomas el usuario
user.updateEmail(String email).then(function() {
  // Actualización exitosa.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Algo salio mal.
  if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
    // El email esta mal formado
  } else if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
    // El email ya existe
  }
});
```

---

> Recomendación: recuerda siempre imprimir por consola lo que te llega en tus
>   *callbacks* para ver los códigos de errores y saber como manejar los.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías verificar si el email esta registrado con el método **fetchSignInMethodsForEmail** el cual recibe el email como parámetro, posteriormente puedes verificar si ese email tiene un método de acceso, esto lo logras con **getSignInMethods().isEmpty()**, si retorna **true** significa que ese email esta en uso; de lo contrario el email no esta registrado por ende ese usuario no existe.

```
public  void  verificarEmailInFirebase(String email){ 
   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                boolean check =!task.getResult().getSignInMethods().isEmpty();
                if (check){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El email esta en uso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }
                else {    
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El email no esta en uso, por ende el usuario no existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }    
        }
    });    
}
```

Puedes revisar la documentación [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth?hl=es#java_6) en el apartado **Diferencia una combinación de correo electrónico y contraseña de un vínculo de correo electrónico**; donde puedes comprender mejor su uso